# Hibernate Entity - возможно ли получить энтити используя незамапенное поле.

Tags: jpa, hibernate, java

Имеем энтити, например:

```
@Entity 
public class User {...}
```

и таблицу USERS

```
id, name, email, password, roleId
```

в классе мы замапили только

```
int id
String name
String email
```

Возможно ли получить объект так:

```
List<User> users = session.createQuery("from User where roleid=2").list()?
```

т.е. roleId - поле в таблице, но его нет в Entity. 
Подскажите, народ! Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вам поможет [Native Sql](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/html/querysql.html)

Comment: да, но он возвращает Object[] а не нужный мне энтити

Comment: Спасибо, это то что нужно)